# PHPmailer Authentication is set to False, but Authentication was still required

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an Email to alert users of a file being imported.
In the PHP script, I have added "$mail->SMTPAuth=False", but I get the following error when trying to run the script: "SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 553 authentication is required"

If I run this script on a different machine, the SMTP error from above will not appear. I have tried and copied settings from the working machine, but on my own machine it still gives 553 error. I have ask the Email Server Admin regarding any special permission given to the working machine, but there was none. Are there any other settings I need to check?

Currently, I have matched all environmental variables and php's folder content from the working machine.

Comment: Turning off auth in your script will not work if the server requires it, and that's where the error is coming from. It could be requiring auth if you're not on its local network, which would explain the discrepancy between the two locations. There's not enough info here to be any more precise.

Comment: I believe you are right, the working machine is in a different subnet. i.e. working machine is in 123.123.123.* and my machine is in 123.255.255.*.

Comment: After testing with another PC in the same subnet, it worked. @Synchro thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Synchro

> Turning off auth in your script will not work if the server requires it, and that's where the error is coming from. It could be requiring auth if you're not on its local network, which would explain the discrepancy between the two locations.